# Ajax.BeginForm confirm not work Correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Have a nice day,I faced problem when i use  Ajax.BeginForm,its like that when i enter  jquery-1.8.2.min.js its display confirm message but when i click ok img it doesn't delete value but i remove jquery-1.8.2.min.js and click img it doesn't display confirm message but value delete correctly i can't find where is the error please help me Thanks!

This is my code ---

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript">/script>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Employee", new { id = item.EmployeeId },new AjaxOptions
                   {//GetPacients is name of method in EmployeeController

                                 Confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this employee?",
                                 HttpMethod = "Get",
                                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                                 UpdateTargetId = "EnployeeViewTbale",

                  }))
        {

            <input type="image" class="deleteImage" src  ="Content/Images/delete3.png" />


        }
```

Comment: why did you reference jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js twice?

Comment: @LarsAnundskås Oh Sorry i removed it but Still i haven't solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want do delete something, first of all the HttpMethod should be "POST" since you want to delete an Employee by ID( to send data we use POST), second the ActionResult should be anotated as HttpPost.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
  //code here
 return RedirectToAction();
}
```

This is the thing you should do in the first place, then fix the further bugs